# jsPlumb - Drawing multiple connections using single endpoint for source and target

Tags: javascript, svg, jsplumb

I am trying to create more than one connection from a source to a target using only one endpoint.

Basically, when the user tries to re-draw second path to same node from a source, the path connecting the source and destination should split and rejoin at a single endpoint. Also, every connection will have a label attached to it.

So that the diagram would look like, a single line splitting into number of paths to and from same endpoint.

Something like the one attached in the image.

Am just wondering if this can be achieved using the community edition, or should we go for paid version of JSPlumb? [Something like the one attached in the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZggUS.jpg)

Thanks in advance, 
Balaji

Answer (score 1):

Models an Endpoint - one end of a Connection. An Endpoint has an underlying Anchor, which is what determines the Endpoint's position. Each Endpoint can have 1 to maxConnections connections emanating from it (set maxConnections to -1 to allow unlimited Connections; the default is 1).

http://jsfiddle.net/dL1ua517/

HTML

```
<div id="item_input" class="itemin">PROJECT NAME</div>
<div class="down">
    <div id="downstream_1" class="ds">Output 1</div>
    <div id="downstream_2" class="ds">Output 2</div>
    <div id="downstream_3" class="ds">Output 3</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.item {
    height:80px;
    width: 80px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    float: left;
}
.ds {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    border:1px solid brown;
    float:left;
    margin-left:50px;
}
.down{
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    float:left;
}
.itemin{
    margin-top:150px;
    margin-bottom:100px;
    border:2px pink solid;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    float:left;
}
```

Javascript

```
jsPlumb.ready(function () {

    /*Second Instance*/
    var instance = jsPlumb.getInstance();
    instance.importDefaults({
        Connector: ["Bezier", {
            curviness: 150
        }],
        Anchors: ["BottomCenter", "TopCenter"]
    });

    instance.connect({
        source: "item_input",
        target: "downstream_1",
        scope: "someScope"
    });
    instance.connect({
        source: "item_input",
        target: "downstream_2",
        scope: "someScope"
    });
    instance.connect({
        source: "item_input",
        target: "downstream_3",
        scope: "someScope"
    });
});
```